# JavaGame character is not moving accurately while drawing?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, thread-sleep, flappy-bird-clone

for personal practice, I am remaking Flappy bird for desktop with Java, I have managed to get all the pillars generating, screen, bg moving done, but now I have one problem, which is performance.

I sometimes feel that the game isn't moving as fast, and sometimes gets stuck for 0.5 secs or something, but that's not the case, when I move my bird, it's moving a bit weird, looks like its moving too much forward & then to the back, watch the gif in MP4 format:

http://gyazo.com/d7e94c0b772192e5a5dd1d2b61b8c529

What could be causing that? could this be my game loop or the way I draw the graphics? I don't use double buffering, I render simply by calling .repaint in jframe which repaints the JPanel I added.

Game loop:

```
private void gameLoop() {
    new Thread() {
        private long last;
        private long start;
        private int wait;
        public void run() {
            while(game) {
                long now = System.nanoTime();
                long length = now - lastLoop;
                lastLoop = now;
                double delta = length / ((double) Constants.OPTIMAL);
                lastFps += length;
                fps++;
                if (lastFps >= 1000000000) {
                    System.out.println("FPS: " + fps);
                    lastFps = 0;
                    fps = 0;
                }
                update(delta);
                render();
                this.sleep
            }
        }
        private void sleep() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((this.last - System.nanoTime() + Constants.OPTIMAL) / 1000000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

My drawing area:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    int translateAmount = this.game.getLevel().getTranslate();
    g.translate(-translateAmount, 0);
    this.background.render(g2d);        
    this.game.getLevel().renderLevel(g2d);
    g.translate(0, 0);
    this.game.getBird().render(g2d);

}
```

The way I render the backgrounds is this: I add backgrounds one after one, and if a background is outside of the frame, i won't render it.

```
public void render(Graphics2D g) {
    Iterator<RepeatedBackground> itr = this.repeats.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        RepeatedBackground b = itr.next();
        if (this.game.getLevel().getTranslate() - b.getX() >= 300) {
            itr.remove();
            continue;
        }
        if (b.getX() - this.game.getLevel().getTranslate() < Constants.WIDTH) {
            b.render(g);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I move my bird (i dont use delta, used some tutorial on this):

```
private void update(double delta) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.level.getTime() >= Constants.TRANSLATE_SPEED) {

        // move background
        this.level.updateTranslate();
        this.level.setTime();

        // move bird
        this.getBird().move();
    }
}

public void move() {
    this.x += 2 / 1.10;
}
```

What could be causing lag to the bird or the background? Is there something wrong with my rendering ways or game loop?

Fps always printing this:

```
FPS: 1724172
FPS: 1551857
FPS: 1494378
FPS: 1471987
FPS: 1434095
FPS: 1629905
```

Comment: What's `Constants.OPTIMAL` set to?  You never call sleep?

Comment: @MadProgrammer 1000000000 / FPS; its giving me timeout value is negative

Comment: Nevermind, fixed that error, fps is now sutck at 194  - 160 and sometimes jumps over 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your game loop confuses me - but that's not hard ;)

Basically, as I understand these things, it should work something like...

```
while (gamming) {
    now = get current time;
    update game state
    delta = get current time - now
    delay = desired delay - delta
    wait for delay
}
```

You don't seem to be taking into account the amount of time that the `render` and `update` methods "might" take to execute and calculating the time to wait based those requirements...

Now, I'm not sure what your `delta` values is suppose to be...the time through the current second??  So I've left it out of my example...

The following example gives me a constant 25fps, even with the random delays in the `update` and `render` methods

Now, forgive me, I typically work in milli seconds, it's just simpler on my poor, feeble mind.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class TestGameLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGameLoop();
    }

    public TestGameLoop() {
        gameLoop();
    }

    public static class Constants {

        public static final double OPTIMAL = 25; // fps...

    }

    private boolean game = true;
    private long lastLoop;
    private long lastFps;
    private long fps;

    private void gameLoop() {
        new Thread() {

            private long last;
            private long start;
            private int wait;

            public void run() {

                // Calculate the optimal/maximum delay time
                // This is converted to nanos so it can be 
                // used to calculate the actual delay...
                long millisPerSecond = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                long optimalDelay =  Math.round(millisPerSecond / Constants.OPTIMAL);

                optimalDelay = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(optimalDelay);

                // Last start of a "second" loop                    
                long loop = System.nanoTime();
                // While gaming...
                while (game) {
                    // Start of this cycle...
                    long now = System.nanoTime();

                    // Update the state and render the 
                    // current frame...
                    update();
                    render();

                    // How long did that update take??
                    long timeTaken = System.nanoTime();
                    long delta = timeTaken - now;

                    // Subtract the delay from the maximum delay
                    long delay = optimalDelay - delta;
                    if (delay > 0) {
                        try {
                            // Sleep expects milliseconds...
                            delay = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(delay);
                            Thread.sleep(delay);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    // Calculate if we've being running for a second yet...
                    long loopDelay = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(System.nanoTime() - loop);
                    // If the loop has been cycling for a second...
                    if (loopDelay >= 1) {
                        // Reset the loop time
                        loop = System.nanoTime();
                        System.out.println("FPS = " + fps);
                        fps = 0;
                    } else {
                        // Add another frame to the pile...
                        fps++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void update() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Math.round(Math.random() * 20));
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void render() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Math.round(Math.random() * 20));
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice example but why is my fps always near FPS = 1426207

Comment: I figured out that the glithcing on bird stops only at 20 fps, not less or higher, why that? some games may require less than 60 fps to work perfectly?

Comment: Why does yours have such a high reported frame rate??  It could be the way you are calculating the reporting time, as I said, your game loop confused me so I dumped it.  Most screens only refresh at about 25mhz any way, so anything over that is probably getting lost or discarded within the buffer.  Human eyes are also a factor, at above 60fps, most people won't really see a difference...personally, I average most of my animations around the 25fps range, but then I'm only doing simple animations ;)